# Showing day name and month name in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am having a date example `4/29/2015` . I need to change the format of date like "**`Wednesday,april 29,2015`**. How to achieve this using `SSRS`.?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming that your date field is of data type `date` or `datetime` (otherwise you will need a cast in your sql query), this is how you can do it:

- Right click the textbox where your datetime is displayed and choose textbox properties:

[image]

- From the left panel choose Number, then date and choose the desired format:

[image]

- Then you should see the date displayed as:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Your expected format (`Wednesday,april 29,2015`) is not [standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), so you will need the following [custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) format:

```
"dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy"
```

So the date `4/29/2015` will output `Wednesday,April 29,2015` which is closer to what you need than the `D` standard format which will output `Wednesday, April 29, 2015`.

Now that you have the right format, you need to place it on the report.

There are 2 options:

I am assuming you have a `datetime` field called `YourDate` or a `string` field called `YourDateString`.

1. In the Expression:

   - `=Format(CDate(Fields!YourDateString.Value), "dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy")`
   - `=Format(Fields!YourDate.Value, "dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy")`
2. In the report item properties

   - Expression:
     `=CDate(Fields!YourDateString.Value)` or `=Fields!YourDate.Value`
   - Text Box Properties => Number => Custom => Custom format:
     `dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy`